# Btye to Unicode modification and saving into CSV

Tags: python, csv, python-unicode

I can successfully receive serial data in long strings such as `332,10.00,87.00`, the `,` delimiter will help sort the different concatenated values into respective rows in the CSV subsequently.

However, I would like to modify the serial string data `332,10.00,87.00,35.00` by joining the received serial data with another string variable like so:

```
#serial communication
ser = serial.Serial('COM8',9600)
ser.flushInput()

field_names = ['Time Stamp','Sensor 1','Sensor 2','New Sensor']
force_filename_perm = 'Sensor_Data.csv'

def forcerecording():
    global field_names, new_sensor, FIRST_TIMELOOP, force_filename_perm

    if FIRST_TIMELOOP:
        with open(force_filename_perm,"a") as f:
           writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
           writer.writerow(field_names) 
           f.close()
       try:
           ser_bytes = ser.readline()
           decoded_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
           final_bytes = decoded_bytes + "," + str(new_sensor)
           print("Final Decode:", final_bytes) 
           f = open(force_filename_perm,"a")
           f.write(final_bytes)
           f.close()
       except:
           print("Keyboard Interrupt")

while(1):
    forcerecording()
    #Some Operations done to obtain float `new_sensor` value
```

However, the `new_sensor` value would also be shifted to a new line in the printline, i.e.,

```
Final Decode: 332,10.00,87.00
,35.00
```

instead of:

```
Final Decode: 332,10.00,87.00,35.00
```

Additionally, in the CSV file, the `new_sensor` would always appear to be merged with the `timestamp column`  [image: as shown below:]

May I check if this is a Unicode issue (require different syntax to merge string)? As the printline is indicating as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening / appending and closing your CSV file per loop will be very slow, it would be faster if you keep the file open.

You also mix using the CSV library and attempting to create fields yourself, I suggest you stick to using a `csv.writer()`. As the serial data appears to have commas, you can just split it and create a list which can be combined with your new sensor value.

For example:

```
#serial communication
ser = serial.Serial('COM8',9600)
ser.flushInput()

field_names = ['Time Stamp', 'Sensor 1', 'Sensor 2', 'New Sensor']
force_filename_perm = 'Sensor_Data.csv'

def forcerecording(csv_output):
    global field_names, new_sensor, FIRST_TIMELOOP, force_filename_perm

    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
        # Remove trailing newline from decoded_bytes and split the values
        row = [*decoded_bytes.strip().split(','), new_sensor]
        print("Final Decode:", row) 
        csv_output.writerow(row)
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")

with open(force_filename_perm, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(field_names)
    
    while True:
        forcerecording(csv_output)
        #Some Operations done to obtain float `new_sensor` value
```

Comment: Hi @Martin Evans, it works great now, thanks a lot for the suggestion. Really appreciate it.